# No sorting and filtering of last column in CMS

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager

This might be very silly question, but I am still not able to figure out why there is no sorting/filtering available on last column in CMS.

I remember pretty well, it was there in all previous versions of tridion.
Or have I missed something very basic?

The ability to sort on date is very useful. Also can the columns be interchanged by dragging and moving?

[image: No Sorting and Filtering on Last Column]

Comment: I'm able to sort and filter on the date modified column on the systems I have access to. These are 2013 SP1 HR1, but I don't remember any hotfix regarding this functionality. What browser are you using?

Comment: I think I've seen a browser-related issue when zoomed out. Does setting the browser view size to 100% (CTRL + 0 for some browsers) help any?

Comment: Mostly I use Firefox for browsing CMS, but same issue in Chrome as well.

Comment: @Alvin : no change...

Comment: I am also previously facing the same issue in Firefox browser only. But it got fixed automatically by upgrading the browser. Now I can able to filter and sort on date modified column from Firefox as well.

Comment: I have the same issue on 46.0.2490.86 (64 bit) using 2013 SP1 but other browsers work OK

Answer (score 2):

You cannot currently change the order of the columns. However, you *can* sort and filter by the Modified column:

[image: Filtering by modification date in 2013 SP1]

It looks like you have a display issue where the column is shifting up above the other columns. I have not seen that elsewhere, but you can try resizing the columns to the left of it to see if that helps. It might also be related to zooming in your browser -- not all browsers handle that elegantly.

Comment: strangely it appears in Firefox as well as chrome. I think the last column is stretched out of context and I cant even see the column name  'Modified'. tried re-sizing as well as zoom, but no luck.

Comment: Do other users have the same issue? Have you tried clearing your browser cache (from the beginning of time)?

Comment: Other things to check are extensions that might be interfering somehow (both CME extensions and browser extensions).

Comment: Checked directly on server using chrome, it works there.  So not an issue with CME Extensions. Tried disabling all extensions/cleaning cache in chrome on my machine, but didnt help. Might be an OS issue. Other users also have similar issue.

Comment: Hi Peter, I noticed the sorting on the last column (Modified) breaks when changing the column width. Once it occurs the sorting on the last column is grayed out. -Gurminder